# Where is Android Studio's Default SDK location on Windows?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion to run emulators on my Windows 7 PC. When I click "run app" in Android Studio, the Genymotion's emulator does not show up. From other stack questions I discovered one fix for this problem is:

" Reason : Problem occurs because Genymotion is shipped with outdated Android tools.

Solution : To solve this, follow the following steps.

open Genymotion app,
go to Settings -> ADB
select 'Use custom Android SDK tools'
and select location of your SDK.

On Mac with recent version of Studio that would be:
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ "

**My question is: Where are Windows' Android Studio SDKs typically held, and what click path would I use to find where Android Studio SDK is held on a PC?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I guess it placed in

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

by default.

Keep in mind `AppData` folder could be hiden.

Also you can check 'sdk' location in

> File > Settings > Appereance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK

Comment: Yesss! "Android SDK Tools found successfully." Thanks so much, I hope this solves my underlying problem ;)